# npm install error included as both a dev and production dependency

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, npm-install, package.json

```
12915 warn whisper-chat-example@1.0.0 No repository field.
12916 warn The package web3 is included as both a dev and production dependency.
12917 verbose type ProcessTerminatedError
12918 verbose stack ProcessTerminatedError: cancel after 1 retries!
12918 verbose stack     at Farm.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/worker-farm/lib/farm.js:87:25)
12918 verbose stack     at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
12918 verbose stack     at Farm.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/worker-farm/lib/farm.js:81:36)
12918 verbose stack     at ontimeout (timers.js:427:11)
12918 verbose stack     at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:289:5)
12918 verbose stack     at listOnTimeout (timers.js:252:5)
12918 verbose stack     at Timer.processTimers (timers.js:212:10)
12919 verbose cwd /Users/ishansrivastava/Desktop/blocks/Decentralized_Chat
12920 verbose Darwin 18.0.0
12921 verbose argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install"
12922 verbose node v10.1.0
12923 verbose npm  v6.0.1
12924 error cancel after 1 retries!
12925 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

I don't understand what is wrong. How do I solve this? Is it something related with the line **included as both a dev and production dependency**?

While running `npm run dev` I get:

```
sh: cross-env: command not found
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! whisper-chat-example@1.0.0 dev: `cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server --hot`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the whisper-chat-example@1.0.0 dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Comment: It seems that `cross-dev` is a npm package which needs to be installed globally, but it isn't. Try `npm i cross-env -g` before running `npm run dev`.

Answer (score 0):

As the error says, you have the package defined in both dev and production dependencies.

If you need the package to be used in development only, you have to define it ONLY in dev dependencies. 
If you need in in production, remove it from the devDependencies and define it in dependecies ONLY.

About the cross-env, you need to install it as global package with npm install cross-env -g. This way the command will be recognized and don't return an error.